# Changing subnet mask

Tags: subnet

Currently I have a 10.10.10.0/24 network and am running out of IP Addresses. I'm not sure if I change to /22 mask, if I will still be able to communicate with some of the other facilities where we use 10.10.30/24, 10.10.40/24, etc. Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In addition to the pretty good answers: you might want to consider using binary patterns in the future: using decimal 10 / 20 / 30 might be nice to look at for a human, but using 8 / 16 / 24 / 32 results in much cleaner subnetting and supernetting. ;-)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: good answer, I did as recommended and no problems

Comment: What I meant was to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer (just under the vote count and arrows to vote). That accepts the answer, it gives the person who answered some points, and you get a couple of points for accepting an answer.

Comment: It is a courtesy to the people who take their time to answer your questions to show your appreciation by accepting the answer that helped you. It encourages good answer in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change to /22 the network would be 10.10.8.0 to 10.10.11.255, which doesn't overlap with your other addresses.

Whether your routing or filtering will let those source addresses out to your other branches, or whether packets will come back, is another question.  But certainly it's possible to reconfigure your routing/access control to permit your /22 without clashing.

NB: The most complete question on addressing and masking is [How do you calculate the prefix, network, subnet, and host numbers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106) which is the best place to look for understanding these things in detail.

Answer (score 4):

Just to adjust jonathanjo's good response, changing the mask to /22, the network would be from 10.10.8.0 to **10.10.11.255**. You can use ipcalc in Linux to check:

`$ ipcalc 10.10.10.0/22
Address: 10.10.10.0 00001010.00001010.000010 10.00000000
Netmask: 255.255.252.0 = 22 11111111.11111111.111111 00.00000000
Wildcard: 0.0.3.255 00000000.00000000.000000 11.11111111
=>
Network: 10.10.8.0/22 00001010.00001010.000010 00.00000000
HostMin: 10.10.8.1 00001010.00001010.000010 00.00000001
HostMax: 10.10.11.254 00001010.00001010.000010 11.11111110
Broadcast: 10.10.11.255 00001010.00001010.000010 11.11111111
Hosts / Net: 1022 Class A, Private Internet`